# Conditionally change the values of a Series based on the values of other columns

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm experiencing/learning Python with a DataFrame having the following structure:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"left_color"  : ["red", "green", "blue", "black", "white", ""],
                   "right_color" : ["red", "gray", "", "black", "red", ""],
                    "flag"       : [1, 2, 3, 1, 2, 3]})
print(df)

  left_color right_color  flag
0        red         red     1
1      green        gray     2
2       blue                 3
3      black       black     1
4      white         red     2
5                            3
```

My goal is to conditionally change the values of the `flag` Series based on the values of the `left_color` and `right_color` columns. Specifically:

- If `left_color` is missing **or** `right_color` is missing, change the `flag` value to numpy `NaN`;
- If `left_color` is different than `right_color`, change the `flag` value to `0`.

Here's my attempt:

```
def myfunc(left_side, right_side, value):
    if (left_side == "") | (right_side == ""):
        value = np.nan
    if left_side != right_side:
        value = 0
```

```
df["flag"] = df.apply(lambda x: myfunc(x["left_color"], x["right_color"], x["flag"]), axis = 1)
print(df)

  left_color right_color  flag
0        red         red  None
1      green        gray  None
2       blue              None
3      black       black  None
4      white         red  None
5                         None
```

As you can see, the result I'm getting is not the one I initially described. Instead, I'm getting `None` values everywhere. Here's my desired result:

```
  left_color right_color  flag
0        red         red     1
1      green        gray     0
2       blue               NaN
3      black       black     1
4      white         red     0
5                          NaN
```

I would like to understand what is my mistake and how to fix. Additionally, I would like to see if there is a more *Pythonic* way to solve this problem which is computationally more effective.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to return the value in your function.

```
def myfunc(left_side, right_side, value):
    if (left_side == "") | (right_side == ""):
        return np.nan
    elif left_side != right_side:
        return 0
    else:
        return value
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `np.select` as below. I thin, this is very likely be faster than a custom function.

```
df.flag=np.select([df.left_color=='',df.right_color=='', df.right_color!=df.left_color,df.right_color==df.left_color],[np.nan,np.nan,0,1] )
```

**Output**

```
   left_color   right_color flag
0   red              red    1.0
1   green            gray   0.0
2   blue                    NaN
3   black            black  1.0
4   white             red   0.0
5                           NaN
```

Answer (score 1):

You want `np.select`:

```
df['flag'] = np.select((df.left_color.eq("")|df.right_color.eq(""),
                        df.left_color.ne(df.right_color)),
                       (np.nan, 0), 
                       default=df.flag)
```

Output:

```
  left_color right_color  flag
0        red         red   1.0
1      green        gray   0.0
2       blue               NaN
3      black       black   1.0
4      white         red   0.0
5                          NaN
```